# how to create queue array from address list?

Tags: c#, arrays, doubly-linked-list

I am writing a term paper and am having trouble checking it. The point of this work is to create a circular two-way array of `Client` class objects. I sent it to the manager, and he said that some aspects of the program are not correct. He said:

1. Why does the `Сlient` class use an array of references `private Operation[] operations;` instead of an array of objects of the `Operation` class?
2. Why is the `Bank` class using an address list `private DoublyLinkedList<Client> arrayClient;` instead of an array-queue?

```
// Operation class
using System;

namespace DepositLibrary
{
    // Класс операции
    public class Operation
    {
        // Дата операции
        public DateTime date;

        // Депозит операции
        public decimal deposit;

        public Operation(DateTime dateIn, decimal depositIn)
        {
            date = dateIn;
            deposit = depositIn;
        }

        // Получение даты операции
        public DateTime GetDateTime { get => date; }

        // Получение депозита операции
        public decimal GetDeposit { get => deposit; }
    }
}
```

```
// Client class
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DepositLibrary
{
    //Класс клиент
    public class Client
    {
        //Фамилия клиента
        public string surname;

        //Текущий депозит лицевого счета
        public decimal currentDeposit;

        // Совершенные операции клиента
        private Operation[] operations;

        public Client(string surnameIn)
        {
            surname = surnameIn;
            operations = new Operation[0];
        }

        //Получить фамилию
        public string GetSurname { get => surname; }

        //Получить все совершенные операции
        public Operation[] Operations { get => operations; }

        //Получить текущий депозит лицевого счета
        public decimal GetDeposit { get => currentDeposit; }
    }
}
```

```
// Bank class
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace DepositLibrary
{
    // Класс банк
    public class Bank
    {
        // Наименование банка
        private string nameBank;

        // Клиентские банковские книги
        private DoublyLinkedList<Client> arrayClient;

        public Bank(string _nameBank)
        {
            nameBank = _nameBank;
            arrayClient = new DoublyLinkedList<Client>();
        }

        //Получить наименование банка
        public string GetBankName { get => nameBank; }

        //Получить клиентские банковские книги
        public DoublyLinkedList<Client> GetListClients { get => arrayClient; }
    }

    public class DoublyNode<T>
    {
        public DoublyNode(T data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public DoublyNode<T> Previous { get; set; }
        public DoublyNode<T> Next { get; set; }
    }

    public class DoublyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>  // двусвязный список
    {
        public DoublyNode<T> head; // головной/первый элемент
        public DoublyNode<T> tail; // последний/хвостовой элемент
        int count;  // количество элементов в списке

        // добавление элемента
        public void Add(T data)
        {
            DoublyNode<T> node = new DoublyNode<T>(data);

            if (head == null)
                head = node;
            else
            {
                tail.Next = node;
                node.Previous = tail;

                // for looped array
                node.Next = head;
                head.Previous = node;
            }
            tail = node;
            count++;
        }
        public void AddFirst(T data)
        {
            DoublyNode<T> node = new DoublyNode<T>(data);
            DoublyNode<T> temp = head;
            node.Next = temp;
            head = node;
            if (count == 0)
                tail = head;
            else
            {
                temp.Previous = node;

                // for looped
                tail.Next = node;
                node.Previous = tail;
            }

            count++;
        }
        // удаление
        public bool Remove(T data)
        {
            DoublyNode<T> current = head;

            // поиск удаляемого узла
            do
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(data))
                {
                    break;
                }
                current = current.Next;
            } while (!current.Data.Equals(head.Data));
            if (current != null)
            {
                // если узел не последний
                if (!current.Next.Data.Equals(head.Data))
                {
                    current.Next.Previous = current.Previous;
                }
                else
                {
                    // если последний, переустанавливаем tail
                    tail = current.Previous;

                    // for looped
                    tail.Next = head;
                }

                // если узел не первый
                if (!current.Previous.Data.Equals(tail.Data))
                {
                    current.Previous.Next = current.Next;
                }
                else
                {
                    // если первый, переустанавливаем head
                    head = current.Next;

                    // for looped
                    head.Previous = tail;
                }
                count--;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int Count { get { return count; } }
        public bool IsEmpty { get { return count == 0; } }

        public void Clear()
        {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
            count = 0;
        }

        public bool Contains(T data)
        {
            DoublyNode<T> current = head;
            do
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(data))
                    return true;
                current = current.Next;
            } while (!current.Data.Equals(head.Data));
            return false;
        }

        IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            DoublyNode<T> current = head;
            do
            {
                yield return current.Data;
                current = current.Next;
            } while (!current.Data.Equals(head.Data));
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> BackEnumerator()
        {
            DoublyNode<T> current = tail;
            do
            {
                yield return current.Data;
                current = current.Previous;
            } while (!current.Data.Equals(tail.Data));
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried for a very long time to understand what he wants from me, but didn't come to a normal result. I would be grateful for any help and advice. Thank you!

Comment: Did you translate the questions correctly, there is [ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)? Why didn't you ask "him" for details? I'd personally decline your work only due to comments in russian, but that's me ;) Also consider to do [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) using dedicated site.

Comment: Yes, I think I translated the questions correctly. This is a rather strange person, even if I clarify something with him, he will answer in the same incomprehensible way. It seems that it is really better to ask this question in a Russian SO.